# A question about the elements of $\mathbb{R}[V] \otimes U$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, tensor-products

Reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10306.pdf (Lemma 2.1) ,

I'm trying to better picture the following:

Let $V,U$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and let $\mathbb{R}[V]$ denote the space of polynomials on $V$.

- How do the elements of the space $\mathbb{R}[V] \otimes U$ look like?
- How to prove that the space $\mathbb{R}[V\oplus U^*]$ is an *algebra*, with $U^*$ denoting the *dual* of $U$?
- How to prove that $\mathbb{R}[V] \otimes U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[V\oplus U^*]$ ?

Comment: I don't see what you mean with $\Bbb{R}[V]$

Comment: just the space of polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1, \dots x_n$ where $n = \dim V$

Comment: [That's denoted $Sym(V)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) it is $\bigoplus V^{\otimes n}$ quotiented by the subspace generated by the $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$.

Comment: Do you understand how $\mathbb{R}[V]$ is an algebra?  $\mathbb{R}[V\oplus U^*]$ is just that same algebra using $V\oplus U^*$ as the input vector space instead of $V$.

Comment: well $\mathbb{R}[V]$ is an algebra since we have a well-defined product between polynomials, that is a polynomial as well. But how to formally describe the product in $\mathbb{R}[V \oplus U^*]$ and how to see that $\mathbb{R}[V] \otimes U$ is a subspace?